# Switching from sync to async APS.NET API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, async-await

I have this C# controller which preforming a different SQL functions by string receive as input.

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage GetFunction(string SQLstring)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(SQLFunctions.SQLsyncFunctionGet(SQLstring), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };

    return response;
}
```

I'm trying to rebuild it in Async method:

First I change the SQL sync function to async without any problem:

```cs
public async Task<string> SQLasyncFunctionGET(string SQLString)
```

How do I change the `GetFunction` class to activate it in the Web API that I've built?

```cs
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFunction(string SQLString)
{
    var content = await ???????????????
    return ok(content);
}
```

Comment: var content = await SQLasyncFunctionGET(SQLstring). 
I also recommend reading about [c# coding conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with this stack, so I don't remember if you can return Task<HttpResponseMessage> or not. But if you can, this should work:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetFunction(string SQLstring)
{
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(await SQLFunctions.SQLsyncFunctionGet(SQLstring), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };

        return response;
}
```